NoSQL database (MongoDB) checkpointer classes in langgraph
Is there an available checkpointer class using MongoDB in langgraph today?
I've been searching for it for quite a while now to no avail.
I can only see class langchain_postgres.checkpoint.PostgresCheckpoint from the documentation and the
from langgraph.checkpoint.sqlite import SqliteSaver

from the langgraph example.

Have you found anything? There isn't one as far as I know. I was looking for the same thing but it seems like your best bet for now is to make a custom MongoDB Checkpointer.
It looks doable but a bit trickier than making a custom MessageHistory or something. I might take a stab at it using the Beanie ODM if I get the time cause I'm already using Mongo for chat histories and would like to incorporate langgraph without running a separate db.
If you find anything let (us) know. I'm sure others will run into the same thing. I'm also sure langchain will make a Mongo checkpointer at some point but even that might need to get modified for specific use cases. Like their MongoDBChatMessageHistory for example is sync only last I checked.
EDIT:
I got a Checkpointer to work with MongoDB. I'm using Beanie so your might want something a bit different, but this does work, so far. Basically I just tried to translate the sqllite Checkpointers, but there might be a better approach:
class CheckPoints(Document):
  thread_id: str
  thread_ts: str
  parent_ts: Optional[str] = None
  checkpoint: str
  metadata: str
  class Settings():
    name = "checkpoints"
    keep_nulls = False
    indexes = [
        IndexModel(
            [("thread_id", ASCENDING), ("thread_ts", ASCENDING)],
            unique=True, 
            name="thread_idx"
        )
    ]


class AsyncMongoDBSaver(BaseCheckpointSaver):

  def __init__(
    self,
    *,
    serde: Optional[SerializerProtocol] = None,
) -> None:
    super().__init__(serde=serde)


  async def aget_tuple(self, config: RunnableConfig) -> Optional[CheckpointTuple]:
    thread_id = config['configurable']['thread_id']
    thread_ts = config['configurable'].get('thread_ts')
    
    if thread_ts:
        checkpoint = await CheckPoints.find_one(CheckPoints.thread_id == thread_id, CheckPoints.thread_ts == thread_ts)
        if checkpoint:
            return CheckpointTuple(
                config,
                self.serde.loads(checkpoint.checkpoint),
                self.serde.loads(checkpoint.metadata) if checkpoint.metadata else {},
                {'configurable': {'thread_id': thread_id, 'thread_ts': checkpoint.parent_ts}} if checkpoint.parent_ts else None
            )
    else:
        checkpoint = await CheckPoints.find(CheckPoints.thread_id == thread_id).sort("-thread_ts").limit(1).to_list()
        if checkpoint:
            return CheckpointTuple(
                {'configurable': {'thread_id': thread_id, 'thread_ts': thread_ts}},
                self.serde.loads(checkpoint[0].checkpoint),
                self.serde.loads(checkpoint[0].metadata) if checkpoint[0].metadata else {},
                {'configurable': {'thread_id': thread_id, 'thread_ts': checkpoint[0].parent_ts}} if checkpoint[0].parent_ts else None
            )
    


  async def alist(
    self,
    config: RunnableConfig,
    *,
    before: Optional[RunnableConfig] = None,
    limit: Optional[int] = None
) -> AsyncIterator[CheckpointTuple]:

    thread_id = config['configurable']['thread_id']
    query = CheckPoints.find(CheckPoints.thread_id == thread_id)

    if before and 'thread_ts' in before['configurable']:
        query = query.find(CheckPoints.thread_ts < before['configurable']['thread_ts'])

    query = query.sort("-thread_ts") 

    if limit:
        query = query.limit(limit)

    async for checkpoint in query:
        yield CheckpointTuple(
            {"configurable": {"thread_id": checkpoint.thread_id, "thread_ts": checkpoint.thread_ts}},
            self.serde.loads(checkpoint.checkpoint),
            self.serde.loads(checkpoint.metadata) if checkpoint.metadata else {},
            {'configurable': {'thread_id': checkpoint.thread_id, 'thread_ts': checkpoint.parent_ts}} if checkpoint.parent_ts else None
        ) 

  async def aput(
    self,
    config: RunnableConfig,
    checkpoint: Checkpoint,
    metadata: CheckpointMetadata,
) -> RunnableConfig:
    
 
    cp_doc = CheckPoints(
        thread_id=config['configurable']['thread_id'],
        thread_ts=checkpoint['id'], 
        parent_ts=config['configurable'].get('thread_ts'),
        checkpoint=self.serde.dumps(checkpoint),  
        metadata=self.serde.dumps(metadata)  
    )

    await cp_doc.save()  

    return RunnableConfig(
        configurable={
            "thread_id": config['configurable']['thread_id'],
            "thread_ts": checkpoint['id'],
        }
    )

I haven't figured out metadata filtering yet with asearch. The metadata object is stored as a string currently - same as the sqllite examples using serde - and I can't get BaseMessage to serialize correctly in metadata.writes to store metadata as an object. A single message gets turned into a list of lists for whatever reason. I don't think asearch is actually used at all by langgraph internally, it looks like just a convenience method, but it'd be nice to get that to work.

No I haven't found any. What I did was I just used the MongoDBChatMessageHistory, get the messages, append the new prompt to that messages and pass that updated messages to the graph. then I also append the response of the graph to that messages so that i keep history updated. But I will definitely check this out!

@JCm I've been using the above checkpointer since I posted it pretty much as-is without any issues. All I added was a user_id field. I have a fastapi/react llm app that I converted from an async version of MongoDBChatMessageHistory I hacked together to langgraph and it works great so far. All you need to do to get the messages from mongo for a particular config is:
history = await memory.aget_tuple(config=config); messages = history.checkpoint.get('channel_values').get('messages'), where memory is an instance of AsyncMongoDBSaver.
